# EXT-JS 4x, not able to see the output

Tags: extjs

I'm pretty much new to EXT-Js and I'm trying to run a few sample programs in my eclipse IDE. When I try to run the below sample, I'm not able to see any output in the browser (IE9) and when I checked the browser console, there were no errors. But when I put the same code into the `Ext.onReady` function, I'm able to see the desired output. Could anyone please explain me if I'm missing somethig here...Just wanted to make sure what this render would be doing (Also, I tried to place a div in the html page and give the div id to the `renderto` attribute, but of no luck)...

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    //layout: 'row',
    title: 'Container Panel',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Child Panel 1',
            height: 100,
            width: '75%',
            html: 'This is chile 1'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Child Panel 2',
            height: 100,
            width: '75%',
            html: 'This is chile 2'
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything really - `Ext.onReady` is exactly the right place to do this kind of setup. It marks the point when the scripts required by ExtJS have been loaded.

Comment: Hi Rob Agar, thanks for the comment. Then what exactly is the use of renderto in extjs.....

Comment: That just tells ext where in the existing DOM tree you want to insert the panel - in this case as a direct child of the the page <body>